# write error: Invalid argument using linux remoteproc on BeagleBone Black

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, remote-process

I have been trying to further understand the Sitara Am335x PRUs and I tried to follow the TI labs on how to get started with Programmable real-time units on the BeagleBone Black and but I encountred this problem that I couldn't overcome;

```
sudo -i  
cp /home/debian/pru_blinky.out /lib/firmware/pru_blinky
cd /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc1  
echo 'pru_blinky' > firmware
```

but when I type `echo 'start' > state` I get the following error

this is the return of `man echo`

```
NAME
   echo - display a line of text

SYNOPSIS
   echo [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
   echo LONG-OPTION

DESCRIPTION
   Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

   -n     do not output the trailing newline

   -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

   -E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)

   --help display this help and exit

   --version
          output version information and exit



-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I tried to to specify the directory and file with command: `echo 'pru_blinky/pru_blinky.out' > firmware` but still problem not solved
can anyone explain to me what am i doing wrong here

Comment: What is the nature of `state` file ? Is that a regular file ? Or an I/O ?

Comment: it's supposed to be an output, to control an LED

Comment: What kind of output ? I don't know the stuff you use but in my understanding if it's a register of some GPIO of course `echo` command can't write text in it.

Comment: it's an output register yeah, can you please explain why the echo command can't write to it

Comment: Cause `echo` aim is to output a line of text (see here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) but a given shell can overwrite the echo command. Can you edit your post and give the return of `man echo` please ?

Comment: i get what you are trying to say, i am following this exemple " https://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-genbeaglebone/blog/2019/05/14/coding-for-the-beaglebone-pru-with-c-in-2019 "  as an initiation on how to use PRUs on the beaglebone black board and the last command dosen't work as it returns the stated error

Comment: edit : the extention of state is .swp file

Comment: I found the error after checking the kernel log I found out that there is a header file that must be provided so that the PRU can execute the program